# Finding free subgroups thanks to Lie algebras

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-algebras, free-groups

Let $f : F \to G$ be a homomorphism from a free group $F$ to a group $G$. I heard that, in order to verify whether or not $f$ is one-to-one, it is possible to associate a Lie algebra $E_0^*(H)$ to any group $H$ using its derived series, and then to consider the associated map $$E_0^*(f) : E_0^*(F) \to E_0^*(G).$$

Unfortunately, I never really studied Lie algebras so the argument was obscur for me. Do you have a reference where I could find some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

For any group $G$ denote by $G=G_1\supseteq G_2\supseteq G_3\supseteq \ldots$ the descending lower central series of $G$ defined inductively by $G_1 = G$ and
$G_k = [G_{k−1},G_1]$ for $k\ge 2$. Then
$$
gr(G)=\bigoplus_{i\ge 1} \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}
$$
is the associated graded Lie ring, where the Lie bracket is induced by the group commutator.
Let 
$$
\mathfrak{g}=gr(G)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}
$$
be the correspondig graded Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$. For references and related generalizations see the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94860/lie-algebra-for-a-general-group). There is also, among others, an article by [Labute](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F1985-288-01%2FS0002-9947-1985-0773046-8%2FS0002-9947-1985-0773046-8.pdf&ei=DP5lVLPcOoT1avH1grAF&usg=AFQjCNFudo9v2pHdW5JIbqzuPsSusZFKWw&bvm=bv.79400599,d.d2s) on this subject.